# Difference between how MOV and MP4 files are treated in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, video, asset-library

For some reason MOVs and MP4s exhibit different behavior in SharePoint Online.  In the image below I have an MOV which displays correctly and runs when clicked, but the MP4 presents a folder containing the MP4, the thumbnail, and an "Other" file.

Additionally, notice the filtering option doesn't present MP4.  Any thoughts here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be simply encoded using an unsupported container. Can you try other mp4s that you know have H264 codec or convert this video in question?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-formats-that-work-in-Office-365-Video-dd1af01c-fd8e-4640-b17b-93ee02b9b817

Here is the codec information for an .mp4 video that is working in SharePoint Online for me:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, If you switch to classic experience,upload the video and add a preview to the file, there will be a folder containing preview image and other contents. Upload videos only in modern experience will not cause such behavior.