# Error Uploading .Mp4 files in SharePoint Online Asset Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, asset-library

I am uploading a .mp4 video file to SharePoint online asset library.The file is around 4 MB.

Everytime I upload the video file , I get the below error:

[image]

Even though it displays error, the file is getting uploaded successfully but its getting uploaded into a folder structure with contents like below:( I'm sure, I'm uploading only 1 .mp4 file)

[image]

Not sure why this is happening. This happens for any .mp4 file I upload on the library. I'm facing this issue in other sites as well. So want to check if this a known issue.

Comment: I have had the same exact problem. I have read some other posts and found that this behavior typically occurs only in classic SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue per my test in SharePoint online modern view.

Refer to this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269420/difference-between-how-mov-and-mp4-files-are-treated-in-sharepoint-online), it seems that the encoded using an unsupported container.

Please ensure the video has the supported video codecs as follows:

- H.264 (Baseline, Main, and High Profiles)
- MPEG-1 (Including MPEG-PS)
- MPEG-2 (Simple and Main Profile)
- MPEG-4 v2 (Simple Visual Profile and Advanced Simple Profile)
- VC-1 (Simple, Main, and Advanced Profiles)
- Windows Media Video (Simple, Main, and Advanced Profiles)*
- DV (DVC, DVHD, DVSD, DVSL)
- Grass Valley HQ/HQX

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-formats-that-work-in-office-365-video-dd1af01c-fd8e-4640-b17b-93ee02b9b817?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us